# NOT NULL constraint failed: plegdetect_fileupload.user_id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am building a plagiarism detector using Django. Whenever a user upload a file and click on upload , That file goes to my media file . But I got the error that NOT NULL constraint failed: plegdetect_fileupload.user_id .
**my models.py is :**

```html
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.
class FileUpload(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**my view.py is:**

```html
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = FileUpload
    fields = ['file']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super(PostCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**my urls.py is :**

```html
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('post/new/',views.PostCreateView.as_view(),name='post-create'),
]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer that in my **models.py**  I did not define the **blank = True** and **null=True** in my user field .
So

```html
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank =True, null=True)
```